# ¿Cómo especificar la extensión del archivo en un for?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en php de registro de archivos, tengo un input file donde puedo subir múltiples archivos, el problema que tengo es que al ser múltiples archivos no puedo especificar el tipo de extensión que tiene cada uno ya que son distintos, quisiera su ayuda en ese tema, este es el código de mi controlador:

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["expArchivo"]['tmp_name']); $i++) {
                if (isset($_FILES["expArchivo"]["tmp_name"])) {

                    $aleatorio = mt_rand(100, 9999);
                    $fichero  = $_FILES["expArchivo"];

                    $ruta = "view/public/archivos/" . $idUsuario . $aleatorio .$_FILES['expArchivo']['type'];

                    move_uploaded_file($fichero["tmp_name"][$i],  $ruta);
                }
               
                $datos1 = array(
                    "e_ruta"  => $ruta,
                    //"e_TipoDoc" => $ruta1,
                    // "e_NumFolios" => trim($_POST["nueNumFolios"]),
                    // "e_NumDoc" => trim($_POST["nueNumDoc"])
                );
                $respuesta1 = ModeloExpediente::MdlRegistrarArchivo($datos1);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes obtener la extensión con [`pathinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.pathinfo.php), por ejemplo:

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES["expArchivo"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

En el contexto de tu código sería algo así más o menos:

```
$ext = pathinfo($fichero["name"][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

**NOTA:** La extensión del archivo se encuentra en la clave `name` de la supergloblal `$_FILES`, no en `tmp_name` ([ver la estructura de `$_FILES`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.multiple.php#53240)).